# Regex not working in R, works in Regex 101

Tags: r, regex

Here is the regex giving the expected output in regex101:

https://regex101.com/r/Xt2mPR/1

Here is the regex failing in R:

```r
str = "<li>\n<a href=\"/kegg-bin/show_pathway?157287994040797/ko00998.args\" target=\"_blank\">ko00998</a> Biosynthesis of secondary metabolites - other antibiotics (<a href=\"javascript:display('ko00998')\">1</a>)\n<div id=\"objectko00998\" class=\"object\">\n  <a href=\"/dbget-bin/www_bget?ko:K02078\" target=\"_blank\">ko:K02078</a> acpP; acyl carrier protein\n</div>\n</li>"
print(str)
#> [1] "<li>\n<a href=\"/kegg-bin/show_pathway?157287994040797/ko00998.args\" target=\"_blank\">ko00998</a> Biosynthesis of secondary metabolites - other antibiotics (<a href=\"javascript:display('ko00998')\">1</a>)\n<div id=\"objectko00998\" class=\"object\">\n  <a href=\"/dbget-bin/www_bget?ko:K02078\" target=\"_blank\">ko:K02078</a> acpP; acyl carrier protein\n</div>\n</li>"

grep('\\/a>(.*)\\(<a', '\\1', str)
#> integer(0)
grep('\\/a>(.*)\\(<a', '\\1', str, perl=T)
#> integer(0)
```

<sup>Created on 2019-11-04 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

What I want is the text: "Biosynthesis of secondary metabolites - other antibiotics"

### EDIT:

Code I used to obtain the string in question:

```r
> scraped = read_html('https://www.genome.jp/kegg-bin/search_pathway_object?org_name=ko&amp;unclassified=K02078')
> scraped %>% html_node('.box2') %>% html_nodes('li') %>% .[[1]] %>% as.character()
[1] "<li>\n<a href=\"/kegg-bin/show_pathway?157288982462113/ko00998.args\" target=\"_blank\">ko00998</a> Biosynthesis of secondary metabolites - other antibiotics (<a href=\"javascript:display('ko00998')\">1</a>)\n<div id=\"objectko00998\" class=\"object\">\n  <a href=\"/dbget-bin/www_bget?ko:K02078\" target=\"_blank\">ko:K02078</a> acpP; acyl carrier protein\n</div>\n</li>"
```

### EDIT 2

Thanks for the help. I used this here: https://github.com/ohsu-microbiome/kegg_http_tools

Comment: Using regular expressions to parse HTML data is generally a terrible idea. You can use a nice HTML parser package like `rvest` to get your data more easily.

Comment: Also, why do you have the `'\\1'` part in there? If you do `grep("\\/a>(.*)\\(<a", str, perl=TRUE)` it works just fine. Looks like this is just a typo. You seem to mixing up `grep` and `sub`

Comment: @MrFlick--That would be totally true if this webpage was coded in any sensible way. I actually am using `rvest` and the best I could do was capture that string as `html_text`. :(

Comment: @MrFlick -- yup. I'm pretty sure I was mixing them up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `sub` instead of `grep` (`grep` returns the indices of matches) to extract strings, and don't use the `perl` argument. I've also altered the regex to replace the entire string with the desired substring, and I use `s` instead of `str` as the variable name because `str` is a function name.

```r
sub(".*?/a>(.*?)\\(<a.*", '\\1', s)

# [1] " Biosynthesis of secondary metabolites - other antibiotics "
```

Comment: Wow! I had no idea about the difference. Maybe `sub` is more like `sed`.

Answer (score 0):

As @MrFlick said, if you're parsing HTML, you're better off with `rvest` package.

In this instance, you could use the `regexec` function along with `regmatches` to obtain all the capturing groups as well:

```
regmatches(str, regexec('\\/a>(.*)\\(<a', str))
[[1]]
[1] "/a> Biosynthesis of secondary metabolites - other antibiotics (<a"
[2] " Biosynthesis of secondary metabolites - other antibiotics "
```

This matches the regex101 output: the full match, and the first capturing group match as well. You can then index by `[2]` to get the desired matched substring.